# Simple redirect_to show path is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to show a resource after it has been created.

routes.rb

```
  resources :eco_systems do
    member do
      get 'new'
      post 'create'
      get 'show'
    end
  end
```

eco_systems_controller.rb

```
class EcoSystemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @eco_system = EcoSystem.new
  end
  def create
    @eco_system = current_user.eco_systems.create(params[:eco_system])
    redirect_to eco_system_path(@eco_system.id)
  end
  def show

  end
end
```

When the `redirect_to eco_system_path(@eco_system.id)` is run, the resulting URL is

```
http://localhost:3000/eco_systems/5
```

Console output:

```
Started GET "/eco_systems/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-14 16:04:22 +1000
  Processing by EcoSystemsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
```

But the page loaded is the new page. Why isn't the show action/view loaded?

Comment: Why do you have the `member` section in your `routes.rb` file? Is `resources :eco_systems` not sufficient for your usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because `show` action is defined after `new` if you run `rake routes` you'll see

```
 eco_system GET    /eco_systems/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"eco_systems"}
            POST   /eco_systems/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"eco_systems"}
            GET    /eco_systems/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"eco_systems"}
```

as routes are checked from the top first action is invoked